# data trigger wpf not working

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, infragistics

i have an enum

```
public enum ConfigFileTypes
{
    NONE,
    CONFIG_FILE
}
```

i want to use xamdatagrid, every time the enum value will be **Config_file** i want to show a **browse button**, for non i want to show nothing, in the future more buttons or options will be added.

i was trying to use xam data grid i was able to get the button created. showing the type of the enum as the button content.

```
<igDP:Field Name="ConfigFileType" Label="Config File">
  <igDP:Field.Settings>
    <igDP:FieldSettings >
      <igDP:FieldSettings.CellValuePresenterStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type igDP:CellValuePresenter}">
          <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
              <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type igDP:CellValuePresenter}">
                <Button Content="{Binding DataItem.ConfigFileType}"></Button>
              </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
          </Setter>
        </Style>
      </igDP:FieldSettings.CellValuePresenterStyle>
     </igDP:FieldSettings>
  </igDP:Field.Settings>
</igDP:Field>
```

[image]

now i'm trying to use data trigger in order to control the visibility of the button (is that the correct way to do this?)

```
<igDP:Field Name="ConfigFileType" Label="Config File">
 <igDP:Field.Settings>
   <igDP:FieldSettings >
     <igDP:FieldSettings.CellValuePresenterStyle>
      <Style TargetType="{x:Type igDP:CellValuePresenter}">

        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=ConfigFileType}" Value="CONFIG_FILE">
          <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
             <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type igDP:CellValuePresenter}">
               <Button Content="{Binding DataItem.ConfigFileType}"></Button>
             </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
         </DataTrigger>
        </Style>
       </igDP:FieldSettings.CellValuePresenterStyle>
     </igDP:FieldSettings>
    </igDP:Field.Settings>
   </igDP:Field>
```

i can't seem to get the data trigger working

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=DataItem.ConfigFileType}" Value="CONFIG_FILE">
```

In binding instead ConfigFileType it should be DataItem.ConfigFileType. I hope this will help.

Answer (score 1):

```
<igDP:Field Name="ConfigFileType" Label="Config File">
   <igDP:Field.Settings>
      <igDP:FieldSettings >
        <igDP:FieldSettings.CellValuePresenterStyle>
          <Style TargetType="{x:Type igDP:CellValuePresenter}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
              <Setter.Value>
                 <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type igDP:CellValuePresenter}">
                   <Button Content="{Binding DataItem.ConfigFileType}"></Button>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                     <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding DataItem.ConfigFileType}" Value="NONE">
                      <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                     </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding DataItem.ConfigFileType}" Value="CONFIG_FILE">
                      <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                  </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
              </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
           </Style>
         </igDP:FieldSettings.CellValuePresenterStyle>
       </igDP:FieldSettings>
      </igDP:Field.Settings>
    </igDP:Field>
```

thanks to ethicallogics answer i found the proper way to do this.